# Como implementar uma fila prioritária que obedeça ainda outros requisitos?

Tags: python, django, heap

Preciso implementar uma fila prioritária, essa fila além da prioridade, precisa levar em consideração alguns outros requisitos, como alternar entre serviços e profissionais, além claro de respeitar a ordem de chegada do cliente para aquele serviço e/ou profissional.

Meu cenário (hipotético) completo:

Em um hospital temos três serviços oferecidos (isso em qualquer outra empresa pode ser a mesma situação, um escritório de advocacia enfim.):

Consultas, exames que serão realizados no dia e outro serviço que é um agendamento de exames.
 O sistema precisa alternar entre os serviços, tipo, chamou alguém de consulta, o próximo deverá ser de qualquer outro serviço e assim por diante.
O sistema precisa alternar também entre os profissionais, o chamado anteriormente foi do profissional 1, o próximo deverá ser do profissional 2 e assim por diante.

Já andei pesquisando sobre alguma lib ou algum algoritmo e o mais próximo que encontrei foi o heapq do Python mas não consegui adaptar e montar minha solução.

Estou precisando muito de um help, aceito sugestões de implementações, indicações de libs que resolvam este problema enfim.

Já tentei várias soluções e nenhuma mostrou o resultado desejado.

Fico no aguardo.

PS: Fiz várias pesquisas aqui no SO e não encontrei nenhuma pergunta igual, caso seja repetida favor indicar link da questão.

Answer (score 1):

Consigo imaginar algumas formas de resolver isso - mas é complicado: uma task de desenvolvimento profissional - ficaria bem comprido de responder aqui. E - de repente o tempo seria melhor empenhado em criar um pequeno pacote de Python que pudesse fazer isso, em vez de chegar a escrever um exemplo funcional aqui.

Para te dar algumas dicas: o "heapq" do Python normalmente só compara o objeto em si (por exemplo o "número da ficha") - um primeiro passo, se for optar por usar o heapq, é conseguir passar uma função de ordenação que possa ter regras complexas - assim como podemos passar o parâmetro "key" para o `sorted`.  Eu tenho uma resposta no S.O. em inglês que cria uma pequena classse de wrapper do heapq que facilita isso:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875823/108205

Agora, sua função "key" teria que levar em conta informações que são *externas* ao elemento que ela está comparando - por exemplo: qual foi a última sub-fila chamada, e qual foi o último profissional chamado - a função `key` do sorted só recebe o próprio elemento - sem poder olhar o resto da fila. Nesse caso, você tem que aproveitar que tem uma classe customizada, e m vez de aceitar o "key" como parâmetro do `__init__` como no exemplo que eu passei, faça a função `key` dentro da própria classe: e ela vai poder olhar dentro dos elementos que já estão na fila para levar em conta os outros fatores.

Uma outra coisa que você pode olhar é o "[redis](https://redis.io/)" - ele vai ter permitir manter uma fila persistente entre requests HTTP distintos - mesmo que você tenha várias máquinas servindo os requests para sua aplicação (ou vários processos e threads  - que e o normal num ambiente de produção)

Comment: Em termos de fila persistente (não vem pronta, precisa de alguma configuração, mas é pouca) o AP pode olhar também o [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `from itertools import cycle`, neste caso, você consegue fazer que fique permanentemente rodando sobre uma lista, usando a função `next(iter)`. Assim você consegue avançar sobre uma lista de pacientes (por exemplo) enquanto vai alternando uma lista (provavelmente menor) de profissionais.

Seria um código +- assim:

```
from itertools import cycle

class Filas:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dicio_filas = {
            "fila_um" : ["Fulano A", "Fulano B", "Fulano C", "Fulano D"],
            "fila_dois" : ["Fulano E", "Fulano F", "Fulano G"],
            "fila_tres" : ["Fulano H", "Fulano I", "Fulano J", "Fulano K", "Fulano L"]
        }
        self.lista_filas = cycle(list(self.dicio_filas.keys()))
        self.lista_prof = cycle(["Prof A", "Prof B", "Prof C"])

    def verifica(self):
        for i in self.dicio_filas:
            if len(self.dicio_filas[i]) == 0:
                del self.dicio_filas[i]

    def chama_fila(self):
        while True:
            prox = next(self.lista_filas)
            if prox in self.dicio_filas:
                if len(self.dicio_filas[prox]) == 0:
                    self.verifica()
                else:
                    return self.dicio_filas[prox].pop(0)
            else:
                if len(self.dicio_filas) == 0:
                    return None

    def chama_prof(self):
        chamar = self.lista_prof
        chamar = next(chamar)
        return chamar

    def direcionador(self):
        fila = self.chama_fila()
        if fila == None:
            text = "Não há mais ninguém na fila de espera!"
            print(text)
            return text
        else:
            func = self.chama_prof()
            print(f"O próximo é {fila}, favor ir até o profissional {func}")
            return fila, func
```

Então você importa em outro processo (se for no Jupyter, em outra célula)

```
chamar = Filas()
```

E então, para cada vez que executar `chamar.direcionador()` na chamada:

```
chamar.direcionador()
```

Irá chamar o primeiro de cada fila, alternando entre as filas e retirando da fila a pessoa chamada, direcionando sequencialmente para cada profissional. Exemplo:

```
O próximo é Fulano A, favor ir até o profissional Prof A
O próximo é Fulano E, favor ir até o profissional Prof B
O próximo é Fulano H, favor ir até o profissional Prof C
O próximo é Fulano B, favor ir até o profissional Prof A
...
Não há mais ninguém na fila de espera!
```

Ai as tuas listas e dicionários você as customiza/personaliza.

Espero ter ajudado.